# selenium web driver not working

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

When i run the code, browser is opening but not at all loading anything.
i want to login into website using selenium.
im using windows 7 64 bit os and python 2.7.
i have downloaded drivers from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    path="D:\New folder (2)\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64/geckodriver.exe"

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
    assert "Python" in driver.title
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("pycon")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
    driver.close()
```

**screen shot**
[image: screen shot]

when i close the browser it shows this error
error
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 0

Comment: Which Firefox version you are using ?

Comment: firefox version 53.0.3 (32-bit). I also tried with both 32 and 64 bit geckodriver

Answer (score 0):

You main issue is in the `GeckoDriver` *absolute path* which you have assigned to **path**.

You need to pass the argument `executable_path` along with the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* binary through  either of the following options :

- Double back slashes (`\\`)
- Single back slash (`\`) along with the raw (`r`) switch.

So you have to change the line :

```
path="D:\New folder (2)\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64/geckodriver.exe"
```

To either :

```
path="D:\\New folder (2)\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"
```

Or :

```
path=r'D:\New folder (2)\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\geckodriver.exe'
```

Comment: @Svickie7 _Not working_ doesn't throws any linght on what's wrong happening. Update the question with your current code block and the error stack trace for further analysis.

Comment: Same empty window is opening and i try to close the browser,it shows error..selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 0